# How to reliably split a string into multiple variables using PHP

Tags: php

I have a string which I need to split/explode into multiple variables:

```
**Apple $1200 iMac $1400 iMac 1TB (Description Text)**
Apple $1200 iPhone (Description Text) (Description Text)
Apple $120 Earbuds (Description Text) (Description Text)

$brand; $price[0,...,n], $product[0,...,n], $description1, $description
```

Desired output

```
$brand = "Apple";
$description1 = "Description Text";
foreach ($price as $prices) {
//insert into database $productname, $prices, $brand, $description
}
```

The order of the text string will always be the same with the exception that there could be more prices for product variety and one or two descriptions.

```
$org = "Apple $1200 iMac $1400 iMac 1TB (Description Text) (Description Text)";

$keywords = preg_split("/[($)]+/", $org);
print_r($keywords);
```

As seen in the example I cannot split the item/price pair. Is there a way to check for numbers to isolate the price as a separate variable? Also how do I keep the delimiter in the output variables, i.e. ( or $?

https://phpize.online/?phpses=ff4c5f0caf939150f61b4bb5e6eae48b&sqlses=null&php_version=php8&sql_version=mysql57

Comment: I don't think you can do this in a single call. Split it first into brand, prices, decriptions. Then split prices and descriptions into arrays.

Comment: Can be multiple calls. I just need to keep the delimiter flags in the output and it needs to be consistent in case there is only one price/product or more.

Comment: Give a sample of the desire result.

Comment: There is no need to ask [the same question twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68351042/explode-a-string-into-multiple-php-variables)

Comment: Updated. So for each price/product new row in the database, that means for 1st line iMac there would be two rows in the database, one for $1200 and one for $1400 model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do it in multiple steps.

First, use a regexp to split it into the brand, list of prices and products, and descriptions.

The brand is everything before the first `$`. The descriptions start at the first `(` and go to the last `)`.

```
preg_match('/^(.+?)\s+(\$[^(]+?)\s+(\(.*\))$/', $string, $match);
$brand = $match[1];
$price_products = $match[2];
$all_descriptions = $match[3];
```

Then parse `$price_products` and `$descriptions` into arrays using `preg_match_all`

```
preg_match_all('/(\$\d+)\s+([^$]+)/', $price_products, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
$prices = $matches[1];
$products = $matches[2];

preg_match_all('/\([^)]+\)/', $all_descriptions, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
$descriptions = $matches[1];
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is really great! I tried replacing $ with $|€|£ to account for multiple currencies but not sure i placed it correctly. I am not sure how to tackle $price_products pairs using foreach method

Comment: Use a character set: `'/([$€£]\d+)\s+([^$€£]+)/'`

Comment: You don't need to do anything with `$price_products`, it's just used in the `preg_match_all()`.

Comment: I mean to parse $prices and $products pairs for later use in the sql script as I wanted to go line by line with a loop. For the currency i should use that for the first preg_match script, on the full string?

Comment: `foreach($prices as $i => $price) { $product = $products[$i]; ...}`. Although it would be easier if you put both the products and prices into a single, 2-dimensional array.

Comment: Clear, thanks. I am still struggling with $€£. How do I implement this for the first preg match?

Comment: Just replace `\$` with `[$€£]`.

Comment: Fine now, however I am having issues with the charset not displaying EUR and GBP signs on the 2nd array. 1st array works fine though which is weird. https://phpize.online/?phpses=e9a322c342830887a0d0249117edc706&sqlses=null&php_version=php8&sql_version=mysql57

Comment: I reproduced that locally, and it's very weird. Unfortunately, I don't know offhand how to fix it.

Comment: Strange, how about pattern modifiers or custom conversion? https://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php

Comment: It's matching the pattern properly. Something is happening when the string is copied to the `$matches` array. I don't understand why it's fine in the first `preg_match`, but screws up in `preg_match_all`.

Comment: In the end it was the encoding. This works '/([$€£]\d+)\s+([^$€£]+)/u' but not sure why it works without it in the 1st array. But there's a different problem with the decimals or commas... For instance $10.01 or $10,20 does not work

Comment: Your examples didn't have decimals, so I didn't include them. But it should be obvious how to modify the regexp to allow them. But maybe not for you, since you weren't capable of extrapolating from my changes to the second regexp to make similar changes to the first.

Comment: `[\d,.]` matches a digit, decimal point, or comma.

Comment: Yes, not for me - I am still in the dark with the regexp. Anyways it works now, thanks for your support

Comment: sorry for this but I have an additional problem which I cannot solve. How do I modify the delimiter regexp so that descriptions in parentheses are optional?

Comment: Put a question mark after it. `(\(.*\))?`

Comment: Unfortunately it gets broken with adding a question mark https://www.phpliveregex.com/p/B8c

Comment: Change `\s+` to `\s*` to make the whitespace optional as well.

Comment: Also not working https://www.phpliveregex.com/p/B8E

Comment: You're missing `$` at the end. Since the quantifiers are lazy, they match the shortest possible string instead of longest. Adding the anchor will force them to reach the end.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if I understand your need, but I believe you want to split  a string into several parts in an array and each value obtained (key, value) must be converted into a variable whose name of the variable is the key.
If that's true, you use

```
$resultArray = explode ($separator, $string);
extract ($resultArray);
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php

Comment: not sure i can use multiple delimiters with explode and one pair vs multiple pairs